# Config файл при сборке Rpm-пакета

Tags: linux, build, rpm

Собираю rpm-пакет. 
Имеется некоторый файл, содержимое которого одна строка с *символов '1'*.

В *spec-файле* имею следующие настройки сборки

```
%files
%defattr(-, root, root)

%config(noreplace) /path/file.config

%preun
echo "222" >> /path/file.config
```

То есть данный файл помечен как файл конфигурации. При удалении пакета я его модифицирую, записываю туда некую строчку(в моем случае строку с 3-мя символа '2')

Собираю пакет, устанавливаю пакет на дистрибутив OpenSuse 13.2. Делаю установку пакета... 
После установки вижу, создался файл /path/file.config со строкой  с *символом '1'*(исходное содержимое файла).
Меняю этот файл(чтобы он сохранился при удалении пакета), заменяю *символ '1' на символ '3'*. 
Теперь пробую удалить мой установленный пакет.
При удалении пакета я прописал, чтобы у меня добавилась новая строка в этот файл "222".
После удаления пакета я ожидаю увидеть сохраненный файл, содержащий 2 строки

```
3
222
```

В итоге, я вижу файл с одной строкой(только последние изменения, сделанные до удаления пакета)

```
3
```

То есть все изменения, которые я сделал в *postun-скрипте* для этого файла, они были утеряны. Почему так происходит?
Установку делаю с помощью команды **rpm -i**, удаление пакета с помощью **rpm -e**.
Можно ли сделать так, чтобы конфигурационный файл менялся в postun-скрипте, и чтобы rpm учитывала эти изменения при сохранении конфигурационного файла после удаления пакета?

Comment: вы проверяли, выполняется ли вообще скрипт *%preun* при удалении пакета? (`touch /tmp/somefile`)

Comment: Скрипт выполняется, проверял. Я даже делал в скрипте задержку в несколько секунд после моего кода по изменению конфигурационного файла, чтобы посмотреть, а есть ли эти изменения в файле. Изменения появляются, но после того, как он завершает удаление, эти изменения теряются в файле. Вернее он файл удаляет, и делает копию файл с префиксом rpmsave , не смотря на опцию noreplace. Но это уже другая тема. В этом файле есть все изменения, который я делал до удаления, но нет изменения, которые я делаю в postun-скрипте.

Answer (score 2):

попробуйте проверить, выполняется ли вообще скрипт из секции *%preun*, добавив в него, например, такую строку:

```
%preun
...
touch /tmp/somefile
```

если файл `/tmp/somefile` не появится после удаления пакета, то стоит попробовать перенести секцию *%preun* **выше** секции *%files*:

```
...
%preun
...
%files
...
```

---

**обновление**

возможно, подходящим вариантом может быть отказ от управления нужным вам файлом средствами программы *rpm*.

попробуйте вообще убрать его из секции *%files*, и просто создавать его (при необходимости) из образцового файла где-нибудь в секции, например, *%post*.

этот вариант мне кажется более простым и менее затратным, чем попытки выяснить точную последовательность действий программы *rpm* при работе с файлами, объявленными как *%config*.

что вы при этом «потеряете»? насколько я понимаю, лишь возможность проверить принадлежность файла с помощью `rpm -qf /ваш/файл`.

Comment: Скрипт выполняется, проверял. Я даже делал в скрипте задержку в несколько секунд после моего кода по изменению конфигурационного файла, чтобы посмотреть, а есть ли эти изменения в файле. Изменения появляются, но после того, как он завершает удаление, эти изменения теряются в файле. Вернее он файл удаляет, и делает копию файл с префиксом rpmsave , не смотря на опцию noreplace. Но это уже другая тема. 
В этом файле есть все изменения, который я делал до удаления, но нет изменения, которые я делаю в postun-скрипте.

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov, я обновил ответ.

Comment: в принципе ничего не теряю, кроме как вы отметили, принадлежности файла к пакету. Спасибо, наверное так и придется сделать. Но я не пойму, почему он так работает? При сборке deb-пакета там все работает так, как нужно. Может какие-то транзакции в rpm, которые откатывают все изменения?

Comment: @AlexceiShmakov , внутренняя логика работы *rpm* весьма скупо документирована (может быть ситуация изменилась за последние пять лет, с тех пор, как мне приходилось вникать в эту логику). а разобраться мешает не только «монструозность» программы, но и то, что на логику работы оказывают самое непосредственное влияние т.н. rpmmacros, которые в каждом дистрибутиве «затачивают» «под себя».

Comment: спасибо за помощь.